# SQL Select user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query that selects a friend request script that shows the profile pic, the hometown, the userid, and the full name of a user that has requested to be friends with a certain user.

```
SELECT 
    a.hometown, 
    a.first_name, 
    a.uid, 
    a.last_name, 
    b.friend_one, 
    b.friend_two, 
    b.friend_request_id, 
    p.thumbnail 
FROM 
    users a, 
    friend_requester b, 
    profile_pics p 
WHERE 
    a.uid = b.friend_one 
AND b.friend_two = $uid 
AND p.uid_fk = $uid 
ORDER BY b.created DESC LIMIT 5
```

My problem is that instead of returning 1 user for each query found in the friend_requester table, I return 3 instances for example of the same user with different profile pictures. So if a user has uploaded 3 profile pictures which will be stored as

```
id=1, profile_pic=profile_pic1.jpg...

id=1 profile_pic=profile_pic2.jpg... 

id=1 profile_pic=profile_pic3.jpg...
```

I get 3 different boxes of the same user asking to be friends with the logged-in user.

As Hituptony mentioned, I would want to select the latest inserted picture which would be from the 'profile_pics' table in the column 'created'.

Comment: You need to make sure to join `p` to either `a` or `b`. Otherwise, it's a cross join that will match for every row in the previous table.

Comment: gms - No. If the $uid is a key, you don't need to join them, you already guaranteed uniqueness by matching the same static value. The question is whether the optimizer will know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY Uid_FK, get the max created and INNER join back to the picture table (done in my subquery called "MaxPic")

```
SELECT  a.hometown, 
        a.first_name, 
        a.uid, 
        a.last_name, 
        b.friend_one, 
        b.friend_two, 
        b.friend_request_id, 
        p.thumbnail 
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN friend_requester b 
            ON b.friend_one = a.uid
        INNER JOIN profile_pics p 
            ON p.uid_fk = b.frind_two
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  uid_FK, MAX(Created) AS Created
            FROM    Profile_Pics
            GROUP BY uid_FK
        ) MaxPic
            ON MaxPic.UID_FK = p.UID_FK
            AND MaxPic.Created = p.Created
WHERE   p.uid_fk = $uid
```

Comment: Hi Gareth I'm using $uid as a session_id for the logged-in user so your code works great but it incorrectly brings back the thumbnail that matches the logged-in user's thumbnail rather than the friend requester. How would I fix that?

Comment: I think you need to change the where clause to `WHERE a.uid = $uid`

Answer (score 0):

So which picture do you want? The picture should have a timestamp related to it, maybe you can pull the date of the picture and get the one closest to NOW() or curdate() in order to display the most recent picture. ^^ I dont think you can group by order by, but you should SELECT b.created, so you can see the order from which it is retrieving the pictures.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I want the latest inserted picture which would be from the 'profile_pics' table under the column 'created'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a new derived table to your join, you can do this:

```
 SELECT a.hometown, a.first_name, a.uid, a.last_name, 
        b.friend_one, b.friend_two, b.friend_request_id,
        p.thumbnail  
 FROM users a, 
      friend_requester b,
      (Select MAX(Created) as Created, uid_fk from profile_pics) p_date,
      profile_pics p
WHERE      
      a.uid = b.friend_one AND b.friend_two = $uid  AND p.uid_fk = $uid 
      AND p_date.Created=p.Created And p_date.uid_fk=p.uid_fk
ORDER BY b.created DESC LIMIT 5
```

Alternately, you may want to have 'flag' column in your pic table that contains a 1 if the picture is the most recent, and a 0 otherwise, - this type of problem seems like it would come up a lot, and as the database grows, and there are mor old pictures, you will get performance problems if you need to check every entry each time. With a flag, you can index for performance much more easily. Also, this query would simply need an added: where flag=1. Each time you insert a new picture, you make the flag 1, and the flag of all that users other pics you set to 0.

Cheers,
David